# gfortran - Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1)

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I am not entirely new to programming but I'm attempting to utilise an inherited function and this brings several unfamiliar issues.
I'm looking for a little direction on how to proceed.

The function is 250+ lines so I show here just the beginning:

```
FUNCTION Z(XNT,XK,ALFA,VNU,GAMMA)
DIMENSION XPI(365)
COMMON/A01R/XVE(365),XVC(365),DXVE(365),DXVC(365)
COMMON/A02R/XP(365),PSITF(365)
COMMON/V02R/DFI
COMMON/V03R/XMUE,XMUXE,XMUR,XMUXC,XMUC
COMMON/V04R/XQXE,XQEPOS,XQENEG,XQXC,XQCPOS,XQCNEG
COMMON/V05R/XDSE(365),XDSC(365)
COMMON/V05RI/DSEI(365),DSCI(365),DQE(36S),DQC(365)
COMMON/V06R/XPRAT
COMMON/V011/N
PARAMETER (ZERO=0.0E+00,ONE=1.0E+00,PI=3.141592654)
```

My program to use function Z is as follows:

```
PROGRAM Test

REAL FOO
REAL A,B,C,D,E
DATA A,B,C,D,E/3.0,1.0,90.0,0.1,1.4/
REAL XMUE,XMUXE,XMUR,XMUXC,XMUC
DATA XMUE,XMUXE,XMUR,XMUXC,XMUC/0.1266,0.0918,0.316,0.0918,0.15/

FOO=Z(A,B,C,D,E)

FUNCTION Z(XNT,XK,ALFA,VNU,GAMMA)
...
...
RETURN
END

END PROGRAM Test
```

I have looked at how to best pass data to the function Z; there are 5 input directly passed to the function (XNT,XK,ALFA,VNU,GAMMA) but several others that are communicated via COMMON blocks.
I am not practiced enough in Fortran to decide on the best scheme to follow.  I have also tried using a DATA BLOCK.

The first of several error messages is as follows:

```
bash-3.1$ gfortran prog01.f90
prog01.f90:19:

FUNCTION Z(XNT,XK,ALFA,VNU,GAMMA)
1
Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1)
prog01.f90:20.18:

DIMENSION XPI(365)
                  1
```

Is "DIMENSION XPI(365)" a legal statement?

Any hints on a way forward gratefully received.
Tim

Comment: Aren't you just missing a `contains` statement before the function definition?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/fortran/2203/program-units-and-file-layout) may be of some use.

Comment: francescalus, thank you so much, the "contains" was the missing ingredient.  I tried to use a "return" to exit the contain but it gave an error "Error: Unexpected RETURN statement in CONTAINS section at (1)".  Perhaps I have another surplus RETURN?

Comment: Yes.  There should be no `return` outside function/subroutines.

Comment: program prog
      implicit none
    contains
      function f()
      end function f
    end program     Thank you for the link to the example, I see the format now, much appreciated